# Calculating 2 non-definite integrals: $\int \sqrt{3x^4 +x^6 +9x^2} \, dx$ and $\int \sqrt[3]{{\frac{1}{x^2 +1}}}\, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculate the following:

A) $\int \sqrt{3x^4 +x^6 +9x^2} \, dx$

B) $\int \sqrt[3]{{\frac{1}{x^2 +1}}}\, dx$

A) I managed to write $\int x \sqrt{3x^2 +x^4 +9} \, dx$, but then I didn't know what to do because of the square root, even with integration by parts.

B) I tried substituting $u=x^2 +1$ so $du=2x\,dx$ but then I don't have any $x$ for $du$.

Answer (score 2):

In the integral
$$\int x \sqrt{x^4+3x^2+9} \ dx$$
substitute $u=x^2$, $du=2xdx$ to get
$$\frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{u^2+3u+9} \ du = \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{ \left( u+\frac{3}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{27}{4} } \ du$$ and to continue, substitute
$$u+\frac{3}{2}= \frac{3\sqrt 3}{2} \tan \theta$$
you will need to remember the integral of $\sec^3 \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

The two integrals don't appear to be related, so it would've been better to ask them as separate questions. At any rate:

(A) Substituting $u = x^2, du = 2 x \,dx$ transforms the integral to
$$\frac12 \int \sqrt{u^2 + 3 u + 9} \,du .$$
Applying the hyperbolic substitution
$$u + \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{2} \sinh t, \qquad du = \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{2} \cosh t \,dt$$
transforms the integral to
$$\frac{27}{8} \int \cosh^2 t \,dt = \frac{27}{8} \int \frac12 (1 + \cosh 2 t) \,dt = \frac{27}{16} \left(t + \frac12 \sinh 2 t\right) + C .$$

(B) There doesn't seem to be a closed-form value for this indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions. In terms of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) ${}_2 F_1$, we have
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1 + x^2}} = x {}_2 F_1 \left(\frac12, \frac13; \frac32; -x^2\right) + C .$$
More generally,
$$\int (1 + x^2)^a \,dx = x {}_2 F_1 \left(\frac12, -a; \frac32; -x^2\right) + C .$$